# Update Server every n seconds by looping function every n seconds? Python Sockets

Tags: python, websocket, udp, python-asyncio

I'm running this server which receives data. However I want it to update every second. This Asyncio loop says it's running forever but it only receives data once.

What loops can I execute to update message retrieval every n seconds and where should I place these loops? I've tried Threading, For/While Loops etc but I may have been placing them in the wrong places.

What should I do?

```
import asyncio
    import websockets
    import socket

    UDP_IP = socket.gethostname()
    UDP_PORT = 5225

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                         socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
    sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

    while True:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
        #print(str(data))


        x = 1

        async def echo(websocket, path):
            async for message in websocket:
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                await websocket.send(str(data)) #FontWeight Value



        print(bytes(data))


        start_server = websockets.serve(echo, "localhost", 9090)


        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
        #loop.run_forever(start_server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ordinary sockets in asyncio because their blocking `recv` stalls the event loop. You need to use something like this:

```
data = None

class ServerProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def data_received(self, newdata):
        global data
        data = newdata

async def serve_udp():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    server = await loop.create_server(ServerProtocol, UDP_IP, UDP_PORT)
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()
```

Then you to integrate it with the websocket serving code. For example:

```
async def ws_echo(websocket, path):
    async for message in websocket:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await websocket.send(str(data))

async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(serve_udp())
    await websockets.serve(ws_echo, "localhost", 9090)
    await asyncio.Event().wait()  # prevent main() from returning

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Can I call you to ask you a few more questions? I am willing to pay! Thanks in Advance :) @user4815162342